# Using PHP to Display & Sort Data From MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of variables that I need echoed on a page - based on their order in the database.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
$1 = 'Download - First Product';
$2 = 'Download - Second Product';
$3 = 'Download - Third Product';

$downloads = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM tbldownloads ORDER BY downloads DESC');
```

In the `tbldownloads` table, there's a column named `downloads` which has the number of downloads each product has.  The variables above correspond with each `id` for each product in the database.

What I want to do is list my products based on the amount of downloads they've had.  They should be ordered from the most downloaded to the least downloaded products.

Am I doing this the right way or is there a better way to do that?  What I'm getting stuck on is how to check the amount of downloads and then sort them to be displayed...

Comment: What did you do yourself ?

Comment: Why don't you just use `ORDER BY downloads DESC` in the query?

Comment: How can we tell if you're doing it the right way if you don't show how you're doing it?

Comment: can yo post some of your SQL code? so we can see what is happening?

Comment: Post your php code fragment which takes data from database and output (with wrong order for now)

Comment: I've updated my code to show the SQL.  But my problem is that I don't know how to actually output the information I need.  The first part of my code is the information I want shown for each product ID.  I also get a list of each product ID in the order I want them displayed on my page.  But what I don't know is how to actually display the information.

Comment: Are `$1/2/3` your "real/actual" variables? and if so, where/how are they being used? this is a 2-part question.

Comment: voted to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ORDER BY` like below, and change the asterix to the columns you want to fetch

```
SELECT * FROM tbldownloads ORDER BY downloads DESC
```

[edit]
To fetch the result you can do like this

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tbldownloads ORDER BY downloads DESC');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['column_name'];
}
```

But I recommend you use PDO or MYSQLi instead of mysqli* function because you get more features and protection against SQL-injections if you use prepared statements.

Comment: I've updated my code to show the SQL.  But my problem is that I don't know how to actually output the information I need.  The first part of my code is the information I want shown for each product ID.  I also get a list of each product ID in the order I want them displayed on my page.  But what I don't know is how to actually display the information.

Comment: @Jamie are you using MySQL, MySQLi or PDO?

Comment: I've updated my answer now so it includes how you fetch the result.